# Intitutive explanation of why probability of getting an even integer is more when random numbers are multiplied.

Tags: probability, intuition

If n(>1) random integers are selected, then the probability of their product being odd is $1/2^n$, which is less than that of the product being even. But this doesn't sound intuitive to me. If number of even integers are same as that of number of odd integers, then why are even integers "more preferred" as compared to odd integers?

Comment: Even times even is even, even times odd is even, only odd times odd is odd

Comment: If one of the factors is even, the product is as well : Modulo $2$ , the possible residues are $0$ and $1$. Only if all factors have residue $1$, the product will have residue $1$.

Comment: An odd question.

Comment: @JeanMarie It was even answered :)

Comment: @Peter We are both in good shape !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the product is odd if and only if each of the $n$ numbers is odd. And if you have $n$ randomly chosen natural numbers, the odds that they're all odd is $2^{-n}$.